# Cant see Kinect Data in ROS

Tags: kinect, ros

I am working on this project that involves using the Kinect for XBOX 360S with ROS.

I did all the steps mentioned in the ROS Tutorials to have Openni Installed and the Prime sense and other drivers. and when i go to Openni samples i see a output. But in ROS i do a roscore and in another terminal do a roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch. And it loads with the regular calibration warnings and service already registered errors. Then in another terminal i open Rviz which gives a error /.rviz/display_config does not exist. And even though i accept the error and go ahead i see a black window which shows no output ,even if i do all tasks mentioned at the RVIZ Tutorials. Also i tried running "rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image_color" and it shows up a blank window with no output. How do i resolve this and get ros to show my kinect data??

I need to run RGBDSLAM and use this kinect later.

I am on Ubuntu 12.04 and ROS-Fuerte.

Well when i launch the openni.launch it starts as usual except for the errors ¨Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node.

And when i run a rostopic it just says subscribed to the /camera/depth_registered/points and cursor keeps blinking.
Even subscribing to the rectified topics just says subscribed and nothing more happens.

Comment: roslaunch will start a core if one does not already exist. I wonder whether starting roscore before executing roslaunch is causing trouble. Try executing roslaunch without first executing roscore.

Comment: Using roslaunch with roscore open should not cause a problem. I'd suggest running 'roswtf' and 'rxgraph' to make sure nodes are connected as they should be for a first pass. Also check this out to see if this is your problem. [http://answers.ros.org/question/50730/rviz-start-up-error/](http://answers.ros.org/question/50730/rviz-start-up-error/)

Comment: @brnd4n On running roswtf i get 17 Errors "Communication with /camera/depth/metric/ failed.

Comment: And on running rxgraph i get a graph in which all paths are pointing an arrow towards/rosout.

Comment: To get a little more help with this, try posting your rxgraph and some other information.

Answer (score 4):

Try [freenect](http://ros.org/wiki/freenect_stack), there are some problems with OpenNI solution.

Firt, install freenect by

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-freenect-stack
```

After installation, connect your kinect (in USB 2.0 port) and run freenect

```
roslaunch freenect_launch freenect.launch
```

Then run Rviz and set Fixed frame to /camera_link, you can now add PointCloud2 window and select the right topic to view the input.

```
rosrun rviz rviz
```

Hope you enjoy ROS!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I know this is not an answer, however since I am a new user I cannot comment on Preetham's question.

I have a very similar problem, however, when I first run roswtf, I get no errors but when I wait a bit after using rviz or trying to record a bagfile, the openni.launch terminal itself gives me this error:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'openni_wrapper::OpenNIException'
  what():  virtual void openni_wrapper::OpenNIDevice::startImageStream() @ /tmp/buildd/ros-groovy-openni-camera-1.8.8-0precise-20130418-2203/src/openni_device.cpp @ 224 : starting image stream failed. Reason: Xiron OS got an event timeout!
[camera_nodelet_manager-2] process has died [pid 3788, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/lib/nodelet/nodelet manager __name:=camera_nodelet_manager __log:=/home/rosbotics/.ros/log/16b63744-e043-11e2-ac16-080027486aa8/camera_nodelet_manager-2.log].
log file: /home/rosbotics/.ros/log/16b63744-e043-11e2-ac16-080027486aa8/camera_nodelet_manager-2*.log

and roswtf  displays:

unknown network error contacting node: timed out

Warning These nodes have died:

- camera_nodelet_manager-2

found 2 errors

ERROR The following nodes should be connected but aren't:

- /camera_base_link1->/camera_nodelet_manager (/tf)
- /camera_base_link->/camera_nodelet_manager (/tf)
- /camera_base_link3->/camera_nodelet_manager (/tf)
- /camera_base_link2->/camera_nodelet_manager (/tf)

ERROR Errors connecting to the following services: (then it displays a lot of services)

At first After looking around a bit I thought it was a problem with openni and tried using freenect instead, however that too gave a black screen. Then I tried using something completely unrelated to ros, freenect-glview, however that too gave me a black screen.

lsusb shows that all 3 parts of the kinect are connected and I've been able to control the kinect's motor through ubuntu so I know that there is at least a connection established between both.

I am using ubuntu 12.04 and ROS-Groovy.

I would appreciate anyone's help on the matter.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange and thanks for contributing. Read the "About" link near the search bar for a badge.